# Having problems with regular expressions

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string `$var1 = [string]"Wei&#xDF; Steht F&#xFC;r Schwarz"`

As you can see I am getting this weird ascii code which I am trying to replace with underscores `_`. What I wanted to do was something like: `$var1=$var1 -replace('[(&#xDF;)\(&#xFC;)\ ]','_')` but the outcome looks like this: `Wei_______Steht________r_S_hwarz` normally I would say that is okay for my purpose but it replaces also my normal "F" and "c". I also want to expand my regular expression if there will be more ascii code in my upcoming strings. Is it even possible to replace only a sequence of letters without replacing single letters?

Comment: **1)** What language are you using ? **2)** What's the exact expected output ?

Comment: @HamZa I am using PowerShell for this example and I will not change to php, c++, java or anything like that. For this example I wanted the outcome looking like this `Wei__Steht_F_r_Schwarz` or even better `Weiss_Steht_Fuer_Schwarz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's generalize that:

```
$var1=$var1 -replace('&#x[\dA-F]{2};','_')
```

Output:

```
Wei_ Steht F_r Schwarz
```

If you want to replace spaces too, then:

```
$var1=$var1 -replace('&#x[\dA-F]{2};|\s','_')
```

Output:

```
Wei__Steht_F_r_Schwarz
```

May be you'd want the following solution:

```
$var1 = "Wei&#xDF; Steht F&#xFC;r Schwarz"   
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")
$var1 = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($var1)
$var1 = $var1.Replace('ä', 'ae').Replace('ö', 'oe').Replace('ü','ue').Replace('Ä', 'Ae').Replace('Ö', 'Oe').Replace('Ü','Ue').Replace('ß', 'ss')
$var1 = $var1 -replace('\s', '_')
```

Output:

```
Weiss_Steht_Fuer_Schwarz
```

Comment: Thanks this helps although I am having difficulties in understanding it, where do I have to put the spaces in here? Because my outcome looks like this `Wei_ Steht F_r Schwarz` but I would prefer it to look like this `Wei__Steht_F_r_Schwarz` so that I do not have any whitespaces in my string.

Comment: Wow your code does everything I could ask for, especially that last one of yours. You deserve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is :

```
<?PHP
$var1 = "Wei&#xDF; Steht F&#xFC;r Schwarz";
echo preg_replace("/(&#xDF;|&#xFC;)/", "_", $var1);
```

demo here :  https://eval.in/118621

outputs : Wei_ Steht F_r Schwarz

a better example to make it more generic:

```
<?PHP
$var1 = "Wei&#xDF; Steht F&#xFC;r Schwar&#xFC;z";
echo preg_replace("/(&#\w{3};)/", "_", $var1);
```

outputs : Wei_ Steht F_r Schwar_z

demo here  : https://eval.in/118631

Comment: does this also work in PowerShell? Sorry that I forgot to mention it. And if it works, will there be a way to get rid of the white spaces in my strings too?

Comment: i have no idea about powershell but if you want to remove whitespace characters you need to replace [\s+] with anything you want

Answer (score 0):

String: **`var1 = [string]"Wei&#xDF; Steht F&#xFC;r Schwarz"`**

Regex: **`/&#\w+;/g`**

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eM7rU4)

Will match multiple occurrences in strings of any ASCII code, like `&#xDF;` in above.

EDIT:

Looks like you use Powershell, but I hope my RegEx works in that, though I know not of its syntax, I can guess by your given code that below code should meet your requirements:

```
$var1=$var1 -replace(/&#\w+;/g,'_')
```

Comment: When I try it that way in PowerShell, it comments half of my `replace` command out, the reason is that PowerShell uses `#` for writing comments

Comment: @sebastian Never mind, but I am sure there might be some other syntax of RegEx i.e. instead of wrapping it in `/` (as I did), Powershell must be doing something else (and you know it). So you can simply use the RegEx `&#\w+;` along with its `g`lobal flag with the correct syntax and you are good to go :)